# Create a Web Application using Powershell

Tags: powershell, web-application, host-header

I want to create a web application using powershell. Below is a list of commands I execute to achieve this and all works fine. Web application exists everywhere. But I cannot access it by it's url. I think I don't have a good underestanding of "HostHeader" thing.

When I type web application url in my browser I get an error indicating that the broswer cannot find this web site.

And I Insist to use powershell not central administration.

```
$user = Get-SPManagedAccount "Pouyanserver\Administrator"
```

```
$auth = New-SPAuthenticationProvider
```

```
New-SPWebApplication -Name "Mahan Air" -port 8080 -HostHeader "MahanAir" -url             "MahanAir:8080" -ApplicationPool "Mahan Air" -ApplicationPoolAccount $user -AuthenticationProvider $auth
```

what is the problem ? and what is the host header anyway ? when it just does not work?

Comment: you have a web application, but did you create a site collection at its root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host header is the part of the URL, e.g. it is the "mysite" in http://mysite.example.com.  You need to make sure you configure DNS to have an A record of "mysite" that points to the IP address assigned to the IIS site in the IIS Manager.

Comment: How can I configure my dns ? for example if I say that my host header is "MySite". Then how should I tell the system that "Mysite" actually refers to localhost with a different port ?

Comment: You would make sure that IIS responds to "mysite" (check the IIS Site Bindings in the IIS Manager) on the appropriate port (you can use 80, or another port if desired).  In DNS, you would create an A record of "mysite" that points to the IP address of the IIS site binding.  How you set up the record in the DNS server depends on the DNS server software (e.g. it is Microsoft DNS, or BIND, etc).

Comment: IIS Binding is ok ... it says that you can access this web application by "mysite" on Port 8080. But I don't know about DNS ? I think I don't have DNS server role installed on my server ... how can I add a dns record ?

Comment: You should have DNS installed elsewhere.  If you have Active Directory (which you should), then it would likely be on the Domain Controller(s).